# scrollTop() not working in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function scrollTop () {
  window.scrollBy(0, 100000000000000000);
    $("#entry").focus();
}


   function showChat (nick) {
   $("#toolbar").show();
   $("#entry").focus();

    $("#connect").hide();
    $("#loading").hide();
   scrollTop();
   }
```

This code not working in chrome browser but it working in Firefox, so how to use scrollTop () in safari, chrome and opera browser.

Comment: Why not use the jQuery method `.scrollTop()` instead?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I tested it in IE 7 and it works, also in FireFox and Chrome...

If this really don't work try using this:

```
function jumpScroll(amount) {
 document.body.scrollLeft += amount;
}

jumpScoll(100);
```

Comment: @frooty what version are u using?